# declaring vs defining a local variable

Tags: c

I read that there is a difference between declaring and defining a global variable. My understanding is that in the code below, "a" is declared outside the main (no memory is allocated when just declared) and defined only when value is really assigned to it. But in case of variable C no memory is allocated because there is no usage of it. In case of variable d, it is declaration and initialization.
Or is it that the declaration means declaring a variable using extern keyword?

Also what will happen in case of variable d? Does compiler remove this assuming that it is not used anywhere?

```
int a;    // declaration
int c;    // declaration
int d=10;
int main (void)
{
    a=50;  // a is now allocated memory
    printf"%d",a);
}
```

But when it comes to a local variable, do we have the concept only declared but memory is not allocated? I read somewhere that just saying int b; will allocate the memory in stack. Does any memory is allocated to variable b in below case if it is not used? My understanding is "No" because we are not really using that variable and compiler does the optimization and removes b in such case.

```
void func1(void)
{
int b;
printf("Hello");
}
```

I would like to know the exact difference between declaring with and without extern, defining with respect to both global scope and local scope.

**Update**
Clarification for not being duplicate question: The exact question I was asking is with respect to local variable declaration, initialization (Memory allocation) and comparison with global variable initialization/declaration. In globals we use the word "tentative" for just declaring tentatively, but not allocating memory. Why the same concept is not seen in locals is what my confusion. What happens if local variable is declared and not used. Will memory is allocated or not in stack.

Comment: All of your declarations are definitions.

Comment: All three of those `int`s are declarations, not only definitions. I think you'd have to add `extern` to all of them to make them declarations.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Every definition is also a declaration.

Comment: @melpomene: The first two are actually just tentative definitions.

Comment: You have ask multiple questions the last time regarding the same or very similar topic. As SO is no tutorial site, you might be better off searching for such or reading a C book than asking every little piece here. That way you get a comprehensive and structured view instead of little pieces which might not fit together, leading to new questions. Also, the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) itself is worth reading.

Comment: Local variables cannot be declared, only defined.  `extern int a;` at local scope declares a *global* variable with extern linkage whose name `a` is only known within the scope of the declaration.  It is not per se a local variable, and this style is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Memory is not *allocated* upon setting the value of a variable, memory is committed by the linker and the loader to every defined global variable.

Uninitialized global variables are set at program start time to `0`, `0.0` or the null pointer depending on their type.

Uninitialized local variables have indeterminate values until they are set.  Dereferencing them before they are set invokes undefined behaviour.

In your example, `a` and `b` have value `0` when `main` is invoked, `b` should not be evaluated in function `func1` before setting it.

In pre-Ansi C, one could define the same global variable in multiple source files as long as all definitions were identical and none had an initializer.  This coding style is deprecated but still supported for compatibility reasons. Modern linkers will complain about such instances.

Thank you Olaf for your extra precision: `int a;` is indeed a *tentative definition*.  It is allowed to have another definition further down the same translation unit that will provide an initializer.  The rationale for this is to allow initializers to cross refer to other variables, such as in this example:

```
void *p1;   // tentative definition
void *p2 = &p1;   // regular definition
void *p1 = &p2;  // actual definition with an initializer

static void *p3;   // tentative definition
static void *p4 = &p3;   // regular definition
static void *p3 = &p4;  // actual definition with an initializer
```

Tentative definitions become actual definitions in the absence of other definitions in the same translation unit.

In the example above, it would be more readable to use the `extern` keyword and make the tentative definition of `p1` just a declaration, but there is no alternative for `static` variable `p3`.

**Update:**  Local variables cannot be declared, only defined, with or without an initialier. `extern int a;` at local scope declares a global variable with extern linkage whose name a is only known within the scope of the declaration. It is not per se a local variable, and this risky and confusing style is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile

```
int a;    // declaration
int c;    // declaration
int d=10;
int main (void)
{
    a=50;  // a is now allocated memory
    printf"%d",a);
}
```

int `main.o` and analyze the generated symbols with `nm main.o`, you'll get:

```
0000000000000004 C a
0000000000000004 C c
0000000000000000 D d
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

From `man nm`:

> "C" The symbol is common.  Common symbols are uninitialized data. 
>   When linking, multiple common symbols may appear with the same name. 
>   If the symbol is defined anywhere, the common symbols are treated as
>                      undefined references.
>
> "D"
>   the symbol is in the initialized data section.

In other words `int a;` means tentatively allocate unitialized memory for `a` and mark that memory with the `a` symbol. Upon linking, if all translation units have the `a` symbol of this type, it'll turn into one shared definite ("B") unitialized memory allocation (technically not uninitalized because "unitialized" static data is always zeroed). If one translation unit does `int a=42`, it'll turn into one shared definite memory allocation initialized to 42. If multiple translation units attempt to set a value to `a` at the global scope, you'll get a linker error.

If you do `extern int e;` and you use the symbol `e` at least once in your code, then the `e` symbol will be of type `U`, which is like `C`, except it's an error if no linked-in translation unit provides it. If you do `extern int e` and don't use it, no symbol gets generated for it.

To put it shortly, nonextern global declarations do reserve memory and can't be optimized out (except at the linking stage).
Unused stuff on the stack can be optimized out.

Comment: Thanks @PSkocik for good explanation. What about the declaration vs definition of local a variable as I asked in my post? Since locals are in stack, just writing "int a;" and not using it (we may get warnings if enabled) should not be allocating memory right? So how can we say it is declaring and initializing?

Comment: Note that `a` and `c`, while not being **explicitly** initialized, they are required to be zero-ed by the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, well that's what the .bss section does. Nm calls it the unitialized data section. Probably an unfortunate name. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The standard does not mention a `.bss` section, a heap or a stack. These are left to a pecific implementation. And a section alone does not initialise anything, but that is either the loader or the startup code. FYI. `bss` == "Block Storage Segment". Like `.text` (which contains the program code) the name has historical reasons.

Comment: @JonWheelock Yup. That's what my last sentence says. The stack gets allocated once, though. Stack-allocating local variables is just moving a pointer. And the compiler doesn't have to stack-allocate local variables. It can put them in registers, etc. A local `int a;` may get optimized out, or if you take the address of it later, it will be truly initialized i.e. and you'll get and address to an on-the-stack memory location with undefined contents.